# Make nginx wait x seconds before returning the page

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want given page to load after x seconds, for example when someone goes to an URL "https://example.com/examplelocation", the browser will try to load the page for a couple of seconds before nginx will return its HTTP OK with page body, is this possible?
pseudo-code:

```
location ~ ^/examplelocation/ {
  # wait some time and then send the response
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know about [echo module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo/), which can delay the response for given seconds by using echo_sleep.

```
location / {
    echo_sleep 1;
    echo_exec @test;
}
location @test {
    echo $echo_request_uri;
}
```

Let me know if any query.